# Implement k means clustering in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

**How can i implement k means clustering in solr 6.5 ?**

**Requirements :-**

1) I want to cluster the docs at the query time on the basis of their score

2) I have written my own handler and i want to add the clustering function in that handler only such that it does not the ordering of the docs

I had tried to write the clustering search component as below :-

```
<searchComponent name="clustering" enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:true}" class="solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent">
                <lst name="engine">
                        <str name="name">kmeans</str>
                        <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.kmeans.BisectingKMeansClusteringAlgorithm</str>
                        <str name="BisectingKMeansClusteringAlgorithm.clusterCount">4</str>
                        <str name="documents">100</str>
                        <str name="BisectingKMeansClusteringAlgorithm.maxIterations">4</str>
                </lst>
        </searchComponent>
```

My Request Handler is as :

```
   <requestHandler name="abc" class="solr.SearchHandler">
        <lst name="invariants">
            <str name="defType">synonym_edismax</str>
            <str name="synonyms">true</str>
            <str name="indent">on</str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="appends">
            <str name="fq">search_term</str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="echoParams">none</str>
            <str name="wt">json</str>
            <str name="timeAllowed">15000</str>
            <str name="qf">Field1</str>
            <str name="qf">Field2^0.5</str>
            <str name="pf">Field3</str>
            <float name="tie">0.2</float>
            <str name="fl">Field5,Field6</str>
            <str name="facet">false</str>
            <str name="mm">2&lt;-1 4&lt;70%</str>
            <!-- spellcheck -->
            <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
            <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
        </lst>
        <arr name="last-components">
            <str>spellcheck</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
```

How can i add the clustering in this request handler such that my number of clusters is 4 and iterations is also 4

Also whats the difference between

```
carrot.url
carrot.snippet
carrot.title
```

I read the docs definition but i m unable to understand it.

Comment: I think this is an XY problem[1] .
Why you want to cluster your result documents based on score in the first place ?
You know that the score in Lucene is just to give a ranked order and it has no meaning per se ?

[1] http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1):

To add the clustering component to a request handler just :

```
<arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
        <str>clustering</str>
    </arr>
```

Then :

```
    <str name="carrot.url">id</str> -> unique key of your document
    This is the unique identifier for your document.
    <str name="carrot.title">doctitle</str> -> the title(s)/label(s) for your document
    This is the field or list of fields, which are short and tend to be more important to group your documents together
    <str name="carrot.snippet">content</str> -> the content/text/body of your document
```

From the wiki :

**carrot.title**

The field (alternatively comma- or space-separated list of fields) that should be mapped to the logical document’s title. The clustering algorithms typically give more weight to the content of the title field compared to the content (snippet). For best results, the field should contain concise, noise-free content. If there is no clear title in your data, you can leave this parameter blank.

**carrot.snippet**

The field (alternatively comma- or space-separated list of fields) that should be mapped to the logical document’s main content. If this mapping points to very large content fields the performance of clustering may drop significantly. An alternative then is to use query-context snippets for clustering instead of full field content. See the description of the carrot.produceSummary parameter for details.

**carrot.url**

The field that should be mapped to the logical document’s content URL. Leave blank if not required.

Comment: Will it cluster my docs on the basis of the score  and have i written the search component correctly ?

Comment: I want it as my every doc is mapped in some category so i want the category of the docs matching the query. That's y i want to cluster the results on the basis of the score as higher the score it will have a different cluster and I will get my category

Comment: Is there any other alternative for this then ?

Comment: I am not sure I understood at all what it is your requirement, but I don't think at all score is relevant at all.
If you want to navigate the results based on the categories in the results set, I recommend you to just use faceting[1].
If you want to group your results by category, just use field collapsing[2], you have the flexibility to select the group head so you can select score if you want .

[1] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html
[2] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collapse-and-expand-results.html

Comment: I have a web service written in java. So is there any jar which implements k means clustering so that i can directly call the function passing score as an input and get my cluster ?

Comment: Let me try to rephrase your sentence :
"my every doc is mapped in some category" -> my documents have a field called "category"

"so i want the category of the docs matching the query. "-> faceting on the field category should do the trick, and you have the counts as well

"That's y i want to cluster the results on the basis of the score as higher the score it will have a different cluster and I will get my category" -> I don't understand this bit. I guessed it was field collapsing.

Comment: lets say my docs are as below :-
1) Tititle = A, Category = C1, Score = 7
2) Tititle = B, Category = C1, Score = 6.4
3) Tititle = C, Category = C2, Score = 6
4) Tititle = D, Category = C3, Score = 2
5) Tititle = E, Category = C3, Score = 1.4
6) Tititle = F, Category = C3, Score = 1
7) Tititle = G, Category = C3, Score = 1.3
So by k-means, I will have 2 clusters like 1,2,3 as 1 cluster and 4,5,6,7 as 2nd. And My category will be C1 and C2
If i take faceting and i will get C3 as my category which will be wrong.

this is the reason i want to use k-means algorithm

Comment: Ok I understand what you want to do but I'm sorry but I can not get the sense out of it...
What C1 and C2 are supposed to have different than C3 except they are the top 2 categories and C3 is the third ?

You can use field collapsing to get that ( selecting the group head as yuor preference).
Operating any calculus on top of the score amount is highly discouraged as it is useful just for ranking documents and it will change and greatly even from query to query with different amounts.